# Remove duplicate with textjoin and including criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, textjoin

I have a situation that has been killing me. So here's the dataset

[image]

I want to do the text join to give me all countries with sale more than 0. I got the formula below

> {=TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(B2:B6>0,IF(MATCH(A2:A6,A2:A6,0)=ROW(A2:A6)- ROW(A2)+1,A2:A6,""),""))}

So the expected result is **ca, se, uk, us**

What is really weird is right now, the result is **se, uk, us**. But if I change the sales to the below, it works

[image]

So my guess is if the first row doesn't meet the criteria (b2:b6>0), then it will not return that country once and for all, even though the entries after that do meet the criteria. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: In office 365 you can combine TEXTJOIN with UNIQUE and FILTER.

Comment: `=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A6,B2:B6>0)))` would give your expected result in office 365

Comment: Hi P.b I don't use Office365 but Excel 2019. Unique and Filter don't work ehre

Comment: What does this do: ```IF(MATCH(A2:A6,A2:A6,0)=ROW(A2:A6)- ROW(A2)+1,A2:A6,"")``` ? Result of this formula is always true.